# compare arrays and sort a list of arrays with a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
    MyValue = [name:"myValue", apple:3, banana:2];

    ListValue = [
        {name:"value1", apple:1, banana:2]},
        {name:"value2", apple:3, banana:2]},
        {name:"value2", apple:5, banana:1]},
        {name:"value4", apple:3, banana:3]},
        {name:"value5", apple:3, banana:5]}
        ]
```

Could you help me to find a solution to sort a NewListValue with this condition : if each fruit of MyValue is less than or equal to each fruit of each array of ListValue

I would like to have this result :

```
NewListValue = [
{name:"value1", apple:1, banana:2]},
{name:"value2", apple:0, banana:1]}
]
```

Thank you so much !

Comment: Your first array (MyValue) isn't valid syntax.  Is that supposed to be an object (curly braces `{ }`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 MyValue = { "name": "myValue", "apple": 3, "banana": 2 };

    ListValue = [
        {name:"value1", apple:1, banana:2},
        {name:"value2", apple:3, banana:2},
        {name:"value2", apple:5, banana:1},
        {name:"value4", apple:3, banana:3},
        {name:"value5", apple:3, banana:5}
        ];
    
 
    var NewListValue = ListValue.filter(function(element){
       if (MyValue.apple >= element.apple &&  MyValue.banana >= element.banana )
         {
           return element;
         }
    
    });

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(NewListValue ); //demo code
```

I would use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here. However a for loop would also work.

Corrected a lot of syntax errors here. Converter your `MyValue` array into an object and not an array with keys (doesn't work).

Fixed the `ListValue` array.